# excel vba not converting tamplate to word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

> > When I try to generate a word document, it gets stopped at the 80% progress bar and it shows the following error.

[image]

> > When I try to debug it, I see this

[image]

> > I'm getting error in now `For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count`

**My code**

```
Sub FillABookmark(strBM As String, strText As String)
    Dim j As Long
    With ActiveDocument
        .Bookmarks(strBM).Range _
        .InlineShapes _
        .AddPicture FileName:=strText
        j = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
        .InlineShapes(j).Select
        .Bookmarks.Add strBM, Range:=Selection.Range
    End With
End Sub


Sub AddImage(strFile As String, addOrAfter As Boolean)
 
 Dim oImage As Object
 'Dim oDialog As Dialog
 ' Dim oRng As Object
  '   Set oDialog = Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
   '  With oDialog
    '     .Display
     '    If .Name <> "" Then
      '       strFile = .Name
       '  End If
     'End With
    'Selection.Move 6, -1 'moverse al principio del documento
    'Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="[aud_sig_1]"
    'If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
    If (addOrAfter) Then


 Set oImage = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strFile, False, True)
 
 'With oRng
  '   .RelativeHorizontalPosition = _
   '  wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage
    ' .RelativeVerticalPosition = _
    ' wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage
     '.Left = CentimetersToPoints(0)
     '.Top = CentimetersToPoints(4.5)
 'End With
 Else
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    Set oImage = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strFile, False, True)
 End If
 With oImage
     .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
     .Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.5)
     .Width = CentimetersToPoints(2.1)
     Set oRng = .ConvertToShape
 End With
 
 Set oDialog = Nothing
 Set oImage = Nothing
 Set oRng = Nothing

End Sub


Sub PicWithCaption(xPath, Optional ByVal imgType As String = "All")

Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim xFile As Variant


Dim doc As Document
'******Test
'Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
 'xPath = "C:\phototest\"
'doc.Bookmarks.Exists ("photos")
'doc.Bookmarks("photos").Select                'select the bookmark
'*****End test

Dim x, w, c
Dim oTbl As Word.Table, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, StrTxt As String


Set oTbl = Selection.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 2, 3)

With oTbl
            .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitFixed)
            .Columns.Width = CentimetersToPoints(9)
            'Format the rows
            Call FormatRows(oTbl, 1)
End With

    If xPath <> "" Then
        xFile = Dir(xPath & "\*.*")
        i = 1
        CaptionLabels.Add Name:="Picture"
         Do While xFile <> ""
            If (UCase(Right(xFile, 3)) = "PNG" Or _
                UCase(Right(xFile, 3)) = "TIF" Or _
                UCase(Right(xFile, 3)) = "JPG" Or _
                UCase(Right(xFile, 3)) = "GIF" Or _
                UCase(Right(xFile, 3)) = "BMP") And (imgType = "All" Or UCase(Left(xFile, 1) <> imgType)) Then

                 j = Int((i + 2) / 3) * 2 - 1
                k = (i - 1) Mod 3 + 1
                'Add extra rows as needed
                If j > oTbl.Rows.Count Then
                    oTbl.Rows.Add
                    oTbl.Rows.Add
                    Call FormatRows(oTbl, j)
                End If
            'Insert the Picture
            'Dim shape  As InlineShape
            ' ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture _
             '   FileName:=xPath & "\" & xFile, LinkToFile:=False, _
              '  SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=oTbl.Rows(j).Cells(k).Range
                
            Set shape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(xPath & "\" & xFile, False, True, oTbl.Rows(j).Cells(k).Range)
            oTbl.Rows(j).Cells(k).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            
            
           ' With shape
             '  .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
              ' If .Width > .Height Then
             '  .Height = InchesToPoints(1.75)
             '  Else
             '    .Width = InchesToPoints(1.75)
              '   End If
             '   End With
               
            'shape.ScaleWidth = 50
                
            'Get the Image name for the Caption
            'StrTxt = Split(xPath & "\" & xFile, "\")(UBound(Split(.SelectedItems(i), "\")))
            StrTxt = xFile
            StrTxt = ": " & Split(StrTxt, ".")(0)
            'Insert the Caption on the row below the picture
              With oTbl.Rows(j + 1).Cells(k).Range
                .InsertBefore vbCr
                .Characters.First.InsertParagraph
                 .InsertBefore StrTxt
                 .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                 .Font.Bold = True
                .Characters.First = vbNullString
                .Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
              End With
           End If
           i = i + 1
           xFile = Dir()
              Loop
        End If
'End If
End Sub

Sub FormatRows(oTbl As Table, x As Long)
    With oTbl
        With .Rows(x)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(6)
            .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
            .Range.Style = "Normal"
            .Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
            End With
        With .Rows(x + 1)
            .Height = CentimetersToPoints(1.2)
            .HeightRule = wdRowHeightExactly
            .Range.Style = "Caption"
            .Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub rezie()
Dim i As Long
With ThisDocument
 For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count
 Next i
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This line 'Sub FormatRows (oTbl As Table, x As Long)' is referring to an Excel Table not a Word Table.  Given that both Word and Excel have Table objects you need to qualify your use of table to let VBA know which Table type to use.  If you have added a reference to the Word Object model then this would be Word.Table.  However, it is usually simpler to pass a range as a parameter (Word.Range) and then access the first table in the range.

Comment: @freeflow: there is no `Table`-object in Excel - but nevertheless it is good habit to explicitly reference `Word` in a mixed Excel/Word-VBA-environment, e.g. `Word.Table`. Whereas `Excel.Range` vs. `Word.Range` is a must - as you said.

Comment: **A shot in the dark**: Your document is not created in English (Spanish?) and that style name "Caption" is something else in your language? You will have to manually check what the style name is and use that or use style enums as @Ike mentioned . Rest of the code is ok because the error doesn't happen on `.Range.Style = "Normal"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the style enums to be on the safe side when on a non-english system:

`.Range.Style = Word.wdStyleCaption`  (in case you are using early binding - what you are using)

In case of late binding: `.Range.style = -35`

Comment: The code you provide will only work if the Word object model is referenced.  Otherwise wdStyleCaption will be 0 which can be a very confusing bug to track down.

Comment: I already updated the answer - but as OP uses `Table` (which by the way only exists in Word model) I assume he is using early binding).

Comment: The excel object model supports Table.  How do I know? because I'm looking at it in the object browser as I type.

Comment: Where? Using F2 in the object browser I don't get a `table`- object - nor when typing in code: https://i.imgur.com/gaS8Vii.png (`Table` <> `TableObject`)

Comment: Its at Excel.Range.table.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.table?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144208)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: ok - but that's a method - not an object ...

Comment: True.  But its sufficient to cause confusion.

Comment: This seems to be another question - no `Style` problem

Comment: please help me in this line `For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count` now I'm getting an error in this I don't know how to debug it have tried every basic thing but don't get it.

Comment: where is this code located: in Excel or in Word?

Comment: It is located in Excel

Comment: then you have to write `Word.Selection....` if you are referencing a selection in the word-doc - otherwise Excel selection is referenced

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to put the code I did not get where to write `word.selection` it will be a great help

Comment: at the last line of the code where I have written `For i = 1 To .InlineShapes.Count` it given error don't know why but please help!!

Comment: I'm Writing the code in excel VBA and want to put all the data in a word document, for example, want to transfer an excel invoice template to a word document like that soo plz help me It will be a great help to me plz If you can again right an answer it will be great I will be great full to you